# Marker from plugin.google.maps (not com.google.maps) not changing its position

Tags: javascript, android, google-maps, cordova

I'm trying to track my location with a marker but I can't change its position.
So here is the function that is giving me problems; if you need more code, please ask for it.

```
   onSuccessLocation: function(position){   
    currentLatLong = new getLatLong(position);
    if(currentPositionMarker == null){

    currentPositionMarker = new map.addMarker({

    'position': currentLatLong,
    'title': "I'm here",
    'styles' : {
            'text-align': 'center',
            'font-style': 'italic',
            'font-weight': 'bold',
            'color': 'red'
        }})
    }   

    else{
    alert(currentLatLong.toString());
    currentPositionMarker.setPosition(new currentLatLong);
    }

    }

   function getLatLong(position){
    var longitude = position.coords.longitude;
    var latitude = position.coords.latitude;
    var currentLatLong = new plugin.google.maps.LatLng(latitude,                  longitude);
    return currentLatLong;
};
```

I know "currentLatLong" is beign uptated because I can see it with the alert. My guess is that currentPositionMarker.setPosition(new currentLatLong) is not working because I'm not using it correctly. Also, I'm using watchPosition to track the location (it's working fine) It gives my position with 2s timeout and I'm testing with a one plus.

Thank you in advance!

Comment: take out the "new " in setPosition()

Comment: I took out the "new" it keeps the same.

Comment: take out the other "new " too...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this

```
 onSuccessLocation: function(position){   
        currentLatLong = new getLatLong(position);
 //set up marker
    var mylocationMarker = new google.maps.Marker({
          position:currentLatLong,
          map: map,
          title: 'My location'
        });
        };

       function getLatLong(position){
        var longitude = position.coords.longitude;
        var latitude = position.coords.latitude;
        var currentLatLong = new plugin.google.maps.LatLng(latitude,                  longitude);
        return currentLatLong;
    }
```

Also make sure that javascript libraries for google maps is loaded properly.